# Idle, controls quit working

Tags: asp.net

I am still new to aspx. I built a web site using Web Forms. After the site has been idle for a short time the controls quit working(links do not respond, etc...). I am not understanding why. I do use Session variables. Is this a Session expired thing cause I tried increasing the Session.Timeout, not it seems to much shorter than the default or the time I set. Is there something else poss causing the problem?

Comment: This is not normal behavior. More information is needed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea where to start, what else can I tell you about it?

Comment: share a code sample. markup (html) and server side code (C#).

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive, I do not feel it is code - I am good at that part. I am doing ordinary stuff in html, nothing cryptic here, just div's with controls. Not even any databinding in some of the pages, and when there is the same thing happens. So i see this as a global issue and not any one small piece.

Comment: @DonA Given the issue you are encountering/posting. I don't think you are in a position to determine whether it is the code or not.  I'm trying to assist.  Post the code and accept the help... or not.  Maybe there is a ghost in your server. or perhaps its gnomes.  I expect the problem is between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: I think it is an IIS problem - more likely. How about Session State. I am reading on it now. Do you have some ideas there. I am not sharing code or html - no need that's not the problem.

Comment: My current SessionState properties are InProcess, UseCookies, 20 minute timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen in the following scenarios, among others which I have not listed. Each of these is fairly unlikely, as it is highly probable that a random bit of your code is causing this.

**The best option is to start a new project from scratch and see if that project has the same problem.** Keep it basic, and if it has the same problem, you have a hosting issue and IIS might need to be reinstalled, or the computer may be compromised or dying.

**Other possibilities (all unlikely, but possible)**

- You have some HTML that is causing the controls to become obscured. Example: you can accidentally overlay a div across buttons, causing those buttons to appear inactive, but really the user is just clicking on the invisible div that is on top of the buttons.
- You have debugging turned on and a break point has been hit, and you have not told the code to continue executing or to stop debugging
- You have some code which disables all controls (code-behind or client-side)
- The controls are actually active, but you are not seeing reactions because you have either a deadlock or an infinite loop that is tying up your web server
- The application pool has stopped working. Unlikely.
- The IIS website has been stopped. Unlikely.
- The application pool has decided to recycle or become suspected due to inactivity. It can seem like your controls are doing nothing while they are spinning back up if you are operating in a situation where it takes a very long time for your app pool to recycle or fire back up.

Comment: Thanks for that list. The top four are definitely not the culprits. So how do we fix the lower ones?

Comment: If you have access to the windows event viewer, that can give you a clue about random timeouts or application pool recycles